# Find port of ActiveMQ in MacOS

Tags: activemq-classic

I have installed ActiveMQ with using homebrew using this command:

```
brew install apache-activemq
```

After that, I run the following command:

```
brew services start activemq
```

After that, I see the following output:

```
Successfully stopped `activemq` (label: homebrew.mxcl.activemq)
Successfully started `activemq` (label: homebrew.mxcl.activemq)
```

I expected that after going to this address **http://localhost:8161/admin**, I would see the login page of ActiveMQ, but the address does not work.
How to find the port which should be assigned to ActiveMQ? Is there any problem?

Comment: Can you paste the log from ActiveMQ which includes the broker start-up process?

Comment: Also add the default version and a copy of the activemq.xml used by that brew package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced the similar issue while starting the service with brew.

Instead of
$brew services start activemq

Use
$activemq start
$activemq stop

Incase your paths are not set correctly try this

$ sh /usr/local/Cellar/activemq/5.16.2/bin/activemq start
$ sh /usr/local/Cellar/activemq/5.16.2/bin/activemq stop

here, 5.16.2 is the version I have installed, replace this with what ever version you have installed.